# SetOverriddenBrowser / ClearOverriddenBrowser not working on iPhone 3 iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 project that has a view that switches between Desktop or Mobile.

This is the view when you are on the Desktop website...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SwitchView", "Home", New With {.Mobile = True, .ReturnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery})">Mobile View</a>
```

This is the view when you are on the Mobile website...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SwitchView", "Home", New With {.Mobile = False, .ReturnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery})">Desktop View</a>
```

This is the action is calls...

```
Public Function SwitchView(Mobile As Boolean, ReturnUrl As String) As RedirectResult

    If Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice = Mobile Then
        HttpContext.ClearOverriddenBrowser()
    Else
        HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(If(Mobile, BrowserOverride.Mobile, BrowserOverride.Desktop))
    End If

    Return Redirect(ReturnUrl)

End Function
```

On an iPhone 5, with iOS 6 it works perfect.  I can switch from Mobile view to Desktop view and then back to Mobile view again.

On an iPhone 3, with iOS 4.1 it does not work.  It initially correcting shows the Mobile view, I can switch to the Desktop view correctly, but I cannot switch back to the Mobile view.

I've tried replacing the action with...

```
Public Function SwitchView(Mobile As Boolean, ReturnUrl As String) As RedirectResult

    HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile)

    Return Redirect(ReturnUrl)

End Function
```

This makes no difference.  My user agent string is as follows...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-gb) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7
```

If I force my user agent string to be this in IE 10, it works perfectly fine, so I assume it is some sort of iPhone issue opposed to the detection of the user agent.

Anyone know why switching back to the Mobile view does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 minutes after posting I realise the issue.  Would you believe it wasn't working simply because I didn't have the date set correctly on my iPhone!